# What does the - (minus) symbol in front of function name within Clojure mean?

Tags: clojure

I can't get my head around the following. When defining the main function in Clojure (based on code generated by Leinigen), there's an `-` symbol in front of the function name `main`.

I went to the original documentation on clojure.com and found `defn` and `defn-` among other things, see https://clojuredocs.org/search?q=defn. I also searched on Google and found a source that said that the `-` in front of main indicated that the function was static (http://ben.vandgrift.com/2013/03/13/clojure-hello-world.html).

Does the `-` truely mean that the function is static? I couldn't find any other sources that confirmed that. Also I can use both `(main)` and `(-main)` when calling the main method without any problem.

Given the following code...

```
(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!"))

(defn main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

I get the following output...

```
(main)
Hello, World!
=> nil
(-main)
Hello, World!
=> nil
Loading src/clojure_example/core.clj... done
(main)
Hello, World!
=> nil
(-main)
Hello, World!
=> nil
```

I noticed no difference. Output is the same for both functions. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### First, an aside.

Regarding the macros `defn` vs `defn-`,  the 2nd form is just a shorthand for "private" functions. The long form looks like:

```
(defn ^:private foo [args] ...)
```

However, this is just a hint to the user that one shouldn't use these functions.  It is easy for testing, etc to work around this weak "private" restriction. Due to the hassle I never use so-called "private" functions (I do sometimes use metadata `^:no-doc` and names like `foo-impl` to indicate a fn is not a part of the public-facing API and should be ignored by library users).

---

### The "main" function in a Clojure Program

***In Java***, a program is always started by calling the "main" function in a selected class

```
class Foo
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    ...
  }
}
```

and then

```
> javac Foo.java   ; compile class Foo
> java Foo         ; run at entrypoint Foo.main()
```

Clojure chooses to name the initial function `-main`. The hyphen in the function name `-main` is not really special, except it makes the name unusual so it is less likely to conflict with any other function in your codebase.  You can [see this in the definition](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/main.clj#L510) of the function `clojure.main/main-opt`.

You can see part of the origin of the hyphen convention [in the docs for `gen-class`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/gen-class) (scroll down to see the part about `:prefix`).  Note that using the hyphen is changeable if using `gen-class` for java interop.

Using [the Clojure Deps & CLI tools](https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli#_writing_a_program), the name `-main` is assumed as the starting point of the program.

---

If you are using Leiningen, it is more flexible and allows one to override the `-main` entrypoint of a program.

In Leiningen projects, an entry like the following indicates where to start when you type `lein run`:

```
; assumes a `-main` function exists in the namespace `demo.core` 
:main ^:skip-aot demo.core
```

so in a program like this:

```
(ns demo.core )

(defn foo [& args]
  (newline)
  (println "*** Running in foo program ***")
  (newline))

(defn -main [& args]
  (newline)
  (println "*** Running in main program ***")
  (newline))
```

we get the normal behavior:

```
~/expr/demo > lein run

*** Running in main program ***
```

However, we could invoke the program another way:

```
> lein run -m demo.core/foo

*** Running in foo program ***
```

to make the `foo` function the "entry point". We could also change the `:main` setting like this:

```
:main ^:skip-aot demo.core/foo
```

and get behavior:

```
~/expr/demo > lein run

*** Running in foo program ***
```

---

So, having the initial function of a Clojure program named `-main` is the default, and is required for most tools.  You can override the default if using Leiningen, although this is probably only useful in testing & development.

Please keep in mind that each namespace can have its own `-main` function, so you can easily change the initial function simply by changing the initial namespace that is invoked.

And finally, the hyphen in `-main` us unrelated to the hyphen used for pseudo-private functions defined via `defn-`.

Comment: I'm not sure what I was incorrect about. I explained both defn- and -main because the original question asked about defn- as well.

Comment: Edited to clarify.

Comment: Thank you Alan for the additional information, certainly adds up to the answer of bfabry.

Answer (score 10):

All clojure functions are "static" (digression below). Putting a - as the first character in the name of a function does not have any effect on the behaviour of the function. Using the `defn-` macro instead of `defn` makes a function private. `-main` is ~~by convention~~ the name of the main entry point for a clojure program, if you specify an ns in your project definition as the "main" namespace, the clojure runtime will look for a function named `-main` and invoke it.

It's not really "by convention" now I think about it. As it's not configurable for the standard tools. It is the one and only name that clojure.main will look for.

https://clojure.org/reference/repl_and_main

All clojure functions are actually an instance of a java object AFunction, with an instance method `invoke`. So they're not static from a java perspective, but while in clojure land I'd say that they are, as they have no instance that you see. There is also the special case of gen-class, where you define a java class using clojure. In this case you can mark clojure functions as ^:static for the generated java class. This creates a static method in the generated java class that refers to the instance of AFunction.

Comment: Hmm. `clojure.main/main-opt` certainly doesn't allow `-main` to be overridden, but I'd argue that the AOT codepaths matter for more for purposes of determining whether or not it's a convention; and `clojure.core/generate-class` *does* allow `main` to be passed in as an option.

Comment: I'm going to stick with what I said. Using gen-class to create the entrypoint for a clojure program is an extremely unusual case. All of the standard build tools and documentation expect you to use -main and specify a namespace. Leiningen, clj, and boot.

Comment: Thank you @bfabry for answering my question. I was aware of the fact that the macro defn- made the function private, however I could not tell if the hypen in front of main would result in the same behaviour when using the public defn macro. Thank you for pointing out that using -main is simply a convention.